# How can a client deliberately trigger an accept error on a TCP server written in C?

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, server

Consider the following implementation of a TCP server written in C:

```c
struct sockaddr_in client;
int server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

// bind, listen, error handling, etc.

while(1) {
    int client_fd = accept(server_fd,
                           (struct sockaddr *) &client,
                           &client_len);
    if (client_fd < 0) {
        exit(1);
    }

    // do something with client_fd

    close(client_fd);
}
```

Is it possible for a client to deliberately crash this server by sending packets such that the `accept` call fails (returns a value less than zero)?

The man-page (Debian 10) lists errors like the following but I'm not sure if a client is able to trigger any of them:

- > In addition, network errors for the new socket and as defined for the protocol may be returned.
  > Various Linux kernels can return other errors such as ENOSR, ESOCKTNOSUPPORT,  EPROTONOSUPPORT,
  > ETIMEDOUT.  The value ERESTARTSYS may be seen during a trace.
- > EPROTO Protocol error.

I've already tried several rather simple things, like disconnecting the client socket immediately. My next step to approach this problem would be to craft some packets manually, using RAW sockets or a tool like [Scapy](https://scapy.net/) and then trying to find a way to trigger a protocol error.

I couldn't find any information on this so my question is if it's even possible to deliberately do it or if I can stop trying.

Comment: What do you mean by "crash the server"? Looks like you're deliberately terminating it if `accept()` fails. `accept()` can fail, and it will return a number of error codes that are described in the documentation.

Comment: @Havenard My question is if somebody connecting to the server is able to trigger an accept failure deliberately (and if yes, how) or if the errors listed in the man page are solely server errors.

Comment: I suppose so, if you fail to complete the TCP handshake.

Comment: In most cases, you should ask your OS as it provides the comms stack.

Comment: If the client is sending raw packets many things are possible, including a SYN flood, and the client can also flood you via `connect()` followed immediately by `close()`, but I don't believe there is anything the client can do to produce an error in `accept()`. These are all server-side errors, e.g. attempting `accept()` on a UDP or raw socket, or a non-socket, or with a bad target address or length pointer.

Comment: @Havenard If the handshake doesn't complete, the connection is never created, never gets into the backlog queue, and never gets anywere near `accept()`. It stays on a prior queue until timed out.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways for `accept()` to fail, and they are not entirely standardized across operating systems and socket implementations.

It is not a good idea to terminate your server just because one `accept()` call failed.   Better to log an error and wait for the next incoming connection.  A handful of errors like `EINVAL`, `EFAULT` and `ENOTSOCK` might be considered non-recoverable in the example you gave, so you could make the server exit if it gets one of those, but it should be considered carefully in the larger context of your application stack (e.g. if there is a watchdog that will restart the server automatically).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this doesn't answer my question. It's a piece of code I saw somebody write for a simple server application in uni. I'd like to prove that a malicious client can actually exploit this.

Comment: @AlexR: That should be easy enough: just connect from 10k or 50k clients concurrently and get `EMFILE`.  Unless of course the OS is configured with a huge `ulimit -n`.  Also, read the Linux source code to try to find out exactly what causes `ECONNABORTED` - that one sounds promising.